# How to integrate ServiceNow custom application with Azure Devops using REST API

Tags: azure-devops, servicenow-rest-api

How can i establish connection to service now custom application through Azure Devops.
When release happens through Devops,how can i close service now custom application tickets automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> How to integrate ServiceNow custom application with Azure Devops using REST API

We could integrate them through REST API:

[REST API Overview for Visual Studio Team Services and Team Foundation Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

[ServiceNow REST API](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/istanbul-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_RESTAPI.html)

There is a great article about integrating them:

[Integrate ServiceNow with VSTS RM pipelines using PowerShell](https://www.visualstudiogeeks.com/extensions/integrate-servicenow-with-vsts-release-pipelines-using-powershell)

Hope this helps.